# Linear transformation to evalute double integral

Tags: calculus

Can anyone shed light on this question, please?

$$\iint_S(x-y)^2\sin^2(x+y)\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: Mind specifying what $S$ is?

Comment: Sorry, it is double integral

Comment: I grasped that from $dx\,dy$, but still, over what region??

Comment: For a complete answer, you should also specify who $S$ is.

Comment: I is the region over the double integrals.

Comment: This is a question from Apostol book.

Comment: Of all the six questions you've asked on this site, it seems that they were all about solving problems from Apostol (and in [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281206/manual-solution-of-calculus-vol-2) you directly asked for a pdf of the solutions). You seem to be looking for detailed answers, without showing any hint of previous work, which is not the purpose of Mathematics StackExchange.

Comment: Yes, but what? A circle? a rectangle? Do you realize how the specific region heavily conditions the answer?

Comment: The question does say. Just the way I wrote above.

Comment: Sorry, I' ve meant: the question does not say.

Comment: S is the parallelogram with vertices {pi, 0), (2pi, pi), (pi, 2pi), (0, pi).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Define new variable $u = x-y$ and $v=x+y$.

Additional hint: Use [the change of variable formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables). You have a simple linear transformation so the determinant of the derivative of the transformation is just the determinant. After that you can separate the factors of the integrand and have two one dimensional integrals. (Depending what kind of set $S$ is, if it's just a rectangle the separation is easy).

EDIT: Since the transformation is orthogonal ($(1,-1)\cdot(1,1) = 0$) the domain maps nicely (If it's rectangular, also the image will be rectangular.)

Comment: Hmm....So? I am puzzled.

Comment: @Junior also use a transformation of $dxdy\to dudv$.